# Plotting multiple curves using ODE45

Tags: matlab

I am a beginner to using MATLAB, and I need a lot of help to understand what to do here.

I would like to plot multiple curves using different initial conditions to my system of ODEs.

Here is my code:

```
f = @(t,x) [-1*x(1)-x(3)*x(3);2*x(2);x(3)-x(2)*x(2)];

[t,xa] = ode45(f,[0 5],[-1 0 0]);

plot3(xa(:,1),xa(:,2),xa(:,3));

grid on

title('Solution curve')
```

Does anybody know how I could do this?

It would make plotting phase planes a lot easier.

Comment: You want to just plot phase planes in Matlab?

Comment: Yes, or even just have 3 curves from different initial conditions.

Comment: At least you should tell us what error message you receive from MATLAB.

Comment: Heck, I'll settle with 2 curves, but 3 would be excellent.

There is no error code, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: I have code that does this already will post at 950 when i get out of class

Comment: Add the "hold on" line and after that you can plot as many trajectories as you want

Comment: These suggestions are not working. Does anybody how to get both in the same graph at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, you have problems with plotting multiple trajectories. Here is your modified code for the case of two trajectories:

```
title('Solution curve')

f = @(t,x) [-1*x(1)-x(3)*x(3);2*x(2);x(3)-x(2)*x(2)];

[t,xa] = ode45(f,[0 5],[-1 0 0]);

plot3(xa(:,1),xa(:,2),xa(:,3));

grid on

hold on 

[t,xa] = ode45(f,[0 5],[-2 0 0]);

plot3(xa(:,1),xa(:,2),xa(:,3));
```

However, it's better to use loops when you have many trajectories.

Comment: It would be better to have a script that calls a function that will do this. That way you dont need to write a loop every time you want the phase plane. One would aimple change the function definition and hit run.

Comment: I agree. The loop here is just for handling many initial conditions.

Comment: This code isn't working, it is only plotting one curve.

Comment: @Marc It works, but graphically, only one curve is visible because they are superimposed. For instance, add the `'o'` option to one of the plot3 calls, e.g. `plot3(xa(:,1),xa(:,2),xa(:,3),'o');`.